# Javascript tutorial code doesn't work

Tags: javascript

Working through a Javascript tutorial and got to this example that is supposed to write some temperature conversions to the screen. This is the code straight from the tutorial and it doesn't work at all. Prints nothing to the screen.
  I can't find any error if there is one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Chapter 3, Example 4</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      var degFahren = [212, 32, -459.15];
      var degCent = [];
      var loopCounter;
      for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <= 2; loopCounter++) {
        degCent[loopCounter] = 5 / 9 * (degFahren[loopCounter] - 32);
      }
      for (loopCounter = 2; loopCounter >= 0; loopCounter−−) {
        document.write("Value " + loopCounter +
          " was " + degFahren[loopCounter] +
          " degrees Fahrenheit");
        document.write(" which is " + degCent[loopCounter] +
          " degrees centigrade<br />");
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where did you get the code from? It looks like the dashes (`--`) in `loopCounter--` aren't dashes but something else. This should work: https://jsfiddle.net/g0ojv8y5/

Comment: Beginning Javascript 5th Edition

Comment: Oh geez lol. That's quite the bug. But yes you're right, and that did the trick. Thanks. Didn't even know that was possible.

Comment: See: [How does “cut and paste” affect character encoding and what can go wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929812/how-does-cut-and-paste-affect-character-encoding-and-what-can-go-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (just change `−` to `-`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Chapter 3, Example 4</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      var degFahren = [212, 32, -459.15];
      var degCent = [];
      var loopCounter;
      for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <= 2; loopCounter++) {
        degCent[loopCounter] = 5 / 9 * (degFahren[loopCounter] - 32);
      }
      for (loopCounter = 2; loopCounter >= 0; loopCounter--) {
        document.write("Value " + loopCounter +
          " was " + degFahren[loopCounter] +
          " degrees Fahrenheit");
        document.write(" which is " + degCent[loopCounter] +
          " degrees centigrade<br />");
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```