# ckeditor does not replace umlauts

Tags: ckeditor

I encountered a problem with the ckeditor regarding escaping umlauts. It is reproducable with the example editor on http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/classic.html

When I take the word `Bühnenpräsenz` and copy-paste it into the editor and click "source" it is converted to `<p>Bühnenpräsenz</p>`, though I expect the umlauts to be replaced with html entities.

But when I type in `Bühnenpräsenz` and not copy-paste it, the click on `source` shows `<p>B&uuml;hnenpr&auml;senz</p>` which is correct.

Can anyone reproduce this behavior or does know why pasting and typing behaves differently?

Comment: propably related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929812/how-does-cut-and-paste-affect-character-encoding-and-what-can-go-wrong

Comment: it seems that the contents of the clipboard are in a different encoding then when I type into the ckeditor. In my case the the pasted "ü" has 3 bytes, the typed just 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thing is, the "ü" from the keyboard is a U+00FC while the "ü" pasted is a "u" U+0075 with diaeresis U+0308. String.normalize() solves the issue or unorm.nfkc() ([see unorm](https://github.com/walling/unorm))